# Collection View inside View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

In my app, a viewController is controlling a view, downloading some data from the web and displaying it into a tableView. I want images downloaded from the web displayed in a collection view in the same View. I can't figure out how to do this.. In the example project there is a file for controlling the collection view cell, and I did that too. But in the example project the ViewController file is a UICollectionViewController. I would like to use this code inside the same view of the tableview:

```
extension ViewController {
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.cellImageView.kf_showIndicatorWhenLoading = true

        let URL = NSURL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/master/images/kingfisher-\(indexPath.row + 1).jpg")!
        cell.cellImageView.kf_setImageWithResource(Resource(downloadURL: URL), placeholderImage: nil, optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: { (receivedSize, totalSize) -> () in
            print("\(indexPath.row + 1): \(receivedSize)/\(totalSize)")
            }) { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in
                print("\(indexPath.row + 1): Finished")
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Any idea how to do this? Please let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should take a look at this king of tutorial for the basis: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12. TL;DR You have to implement the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol in your view controller and link it with dataSource of your collectionView.

Comment: thanks man! really helped me!